# How to encryption for iphone

Tags: iphone, encryption

I have an iphone native application,in which i am taking credit card details , i want to encrypt this details and then store it into data base and at some point of time i need to decrypt it again..Is ther any way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you not store the credit card information at all.  Especially don't store it on the iPhone.

Comment: I'm one of the developers of SQLCipher, and we discourage the use of embedding the secret key in your source code. It can be done, and people do use this method for obfuscating data, but it is not secure.